# javascript / php > Is there a way to use a regular button to submit information and call a javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've built a function that rotates a picture when you click a button. I would like to tell this function how many degrees I want it to rotate with a text field or something like that and also call a function that's being executed in php that moves a stepper motor. Is there a way to do so? I've tried with a submit button but it doesn't show the animation the way I want to.

Answer (score 1):

Submit button are generally used to submit forms. Although you can use them too, its not recommend. You can simply use `<button />` element. And you can pass the function parameter on the `onclick` event handler of the button.

```
<button id="rotate" onclick= "rotate('35')">Rotate</button>
```

If you want to get value of text field and send in the form.

```
<button id="rotate" onclick= "rotate(document.getElementById('textboxid').value)">Rotate</button>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/frs2c/)

However, calling a function being executed over PHP is a tricky part. There are different ways you can do that:

- Submit the form to the PHP page and assign URI parameters like `page.php?function=test`
- Direct to the PHP page with passing the values in the URI parameters similar to above.
- Use AJAX request to send and receive data.

Comment: I've tried that, but how do I get the number from the text field without submitting it?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm actually fairly new at this and I don't really know how to assign URI parameters nor use AJAX... could you please write an example with this?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, What makes you so sure, I wrote it from your comment? It is a well know fact.

Comment: @EdnaRamirez, That will make the answer really long and off topic also. How about take a step up and try jQuery. Read the jQuery's post request [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)